# copying only 10gb of files from a folder that say contains 100gb using python

Tags: python, shutil

i have this script that copies all files with the file extension txt which scans all the files in the folder and then copies them to another folder. The thing is most of the time there is over 100GB of files in that one folder, what i would like is to only copy over a specific amount of files in size. say only copy 10GB of .txt files. i just can not seem to find from searching how to achieve this.

Comment: Please use the proper SI units. "GB" means gigabytes. "Gb" means gigabits. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabit I am unaware of "gb".

Comment: Are the sizes of files inside the folder always the same? For example, are there 1000 files with  size of 100MB each? Or does it vary from file to file?

Comment: @MarkSetchell thanks for pointing this out. I should of used GB which means gigabytes.

Comment: @ARK1375 the files vary from file to file. so id like to copy say the fist 10GB

Comment: If you click [edit] you can update it.

Comment: What specific technical problem did you encounter while trying to write a program to do this yourself? We don't generally do "please write a program that does X for me" questions; it's expected that you make your own effort and then ask about a narrow, specific problem you encountered that prevented you from completing that effort successfully on your own.

Comment: ...if the problem is that you don't know how to check a file's size, for example, that's specific (and also quite likely already solved elsewhere in our knowledge base). Likewise, if you don't know how to recurse over a directory tree.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy i do know how to check a files size. There is a lot more to the program but in order not to confuse i have simplified the scenario. i don't want any one to write me a program.  i will try and explain a bit more. my program scans through 1 folder at my choice. i have selected all files with the txt file extension. the folder contains roughly say 100GB of txt files. i then shutilcopy the files to another folder. however all the files copy over to the other folder. i only would like to copy a specific amount of GB not the whole 100GB,

Comment: Yes, I understand that (what you just repeated from the question in the above comment), but I don't understand what your _narrow, specific technical question_ is about the place you got stuck. The person who answered this (by writing your program for you) without there being a specific technical question included was breaking our rules by doing so -- see the _Answer Well-Asked Questions_ section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and the links to other parts of the Help Center therein.

Comment: If you look at that answer, it's doing the following things: (1) Finding files; (2) checking their size; (3) adding that size to a total; (4) checking whether the total is over a limit. If, as you assert in the comments above, you already knew how to do (1) and (2)... is it (3) you didn't know? Is it (4)?

Comment: "i have this script" - which script? Maybe you want to post "the script" so the we can find the bug that it has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```py
import os
import shutil

def move_up_to_10GB_of_files(source_directory: str, destination_directory: str) -> None:
    GB: int = 1 << 30
    _10GB: int = GB * 10

    total_size: int = 0
    for filename in os.listdir(source_directory):
        src_path: str = os.path.join(source_directory, filename)
        dst_path: str = os.path.join(destination_directory, filename)

        size: int = os.path.getsize(src_path)
        total_size += size
        if total_size > _10GB:
            return
        shutil.copy(src_path, dst_path)
```

Comment: Myles Hollowed. thanks for understanding my question. this is exactly what i was looking for. many thanks.  Solved :)

Comment: In order to mark this as solved, you can click the check-mark that's on the left side of my answer.